# L'hopital - Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, limits

[image]

I have simplified the expression to $(1/x+\sin x)$. The numerator is neither $0$ nor infinity.

Comment: Make the numerator your integral and the denominator $x^2$.

Comment: Once you verified that the numerator and denominator diverge tp $\infty$, and apply L'Hospital procedure you get $$\frac{1}{2x}\frac{x^2}{x+|\sin x|}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{x+|\sin x|}=\frac12\frac{1}{1+\tfrac{|\sin x|}{x}}$$ Can you finish from here?

Comment: Your "I have simplified" looks fishy.